# How do I verify this scaling relation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have a PDE as follows-

$i\frac{\partial u}{\partial \xi} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \tau^2} + |u|^2u = 0$

My book says that if $u(\xi,\tau)$ is a solution of the PDE, then $\epsilon u(\epsilon^2\xi,\epsilon\tau)$ is also a solution. Why is this true?

Comment: Did you try chain rule? What specific steps are tripping you up? Showing your work would be helpful.

Comment: I am not sure how to apply the chain rule in this situation where the form of $u$ is unknown.

Comment: chain rule never mentions a specific "form", either, it is a very general rule. What is $$\frac{\partial}{\partial \xi} \epsilon u(\epsilon^2 \xi, \epsilon \tau)$$ ?

Comment: Did this come from a book on lasers, by any chance? The time and space variables are swapped from their usual positions.

Comment: I am very unsure about my math skills, but I am guessing the derivative is $\epsilon^3 \frac{\partial}{\partial \xi}u(\xi,\epsilon \tau)$. Is that right? And yes, close enough. It is from a book on nonlinear fiber optics. But if $u$ has a $\xi^2$ term, what happens?

Comment: Almost, you forgot the $\epsilon^2$ on the inside. But $u$ does not have a $\xi^2$, so your point? It would come out front if that were the case, though, if I am understanding you correctly. You're gonna have to be more clear.

Comment: Figures, I recognized this nonlinear Schrodinger from my favorite nonlinear optics textbook, Boyd.

Comment: @NinadMunshi, why can I make the assumption that $u$ does not have a $\xi^2$ term?

Comment: ?? I still don't understand your question. Chain rule is very abstract. Let's say I had $f(x) = x^2$ and I wanted to find the derivative of $g(x) = f(ax)$. We could do it directly $$\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}a^2x^2 = 2ax^2$$ or we could use chain rule $$\frac{d}{dx}g(x) = \frac{d}{dx} f(ax) = af'(ax) = a\cdot 2(ax) = 2a^2x$$ so I really don't understand what you're trying to ask or what you're misunderstanding.

Comment: When I said $u$ doesn't have $\xi^2$, I meant that the scaling wasn't some nonlinear kerfuffle like $$u(\epsilon^2\xi^2,\epsilon\tau\cos\xi)$$ in which case the derivative would be $$2\epsilon^2\xi u_\xi(\epsilon^2\xi^2,\epsilon\tau) - \epsilon\tau\sin\xi u_\tau(\epsilon^2\xi^2,\epsilon\tau\cos\xi)$$ Again, that isn't what we have.